# Facing issue in SVN of Synchronization Operation Failed

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

[image]

I am trying to sync my current project code with the code present in SVN server repository. I have no idea regarding SVN and its configuration. Please refer to the screenshot for the error. Kindly help me why I am facing such an error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your SVN URL...  Experience dictates that majority Cases URL is incorrect....

Comment: Actually the issue was that the SVN server rebooted and services were stopped. I had to restart the services and once done, SVN was up and running. Thanks!